# Google Console OAuth Localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

Is there a way to add `http://somesite:8080` in order to use google's oauth on localhost?
I see that for example `http://localhost:8080` is allowed.
I get this error:

```
Invalid Origin: This app has a publishing status of "In production". URI must use https:// as the scheme.
```

Comment: Your error says it's looking for an ```https``` protocol. Are you sure ```http://localhost:8000``` actually works (cos it's still not ```https```). To get ```https``` for your local machine, look for tunnelling Apps like https://ngrok.com/

Comment: I agree wtih @NoCommandLine, you are required to use `HTTPS` and there is no way for use to bypass this. The policy requires redirect URIs and post message origin URLs to be secured in `HTTPS` format. And If you are trying to access any high-risk data in the project, you will be blocked from using standard `HTTP` format